# Выбор серверной ОС

Tags: ос

Выбираю ОС для установки на сервер - между Ubuntu И CentOS. Есть ли какие-то аргументы в пользу одной из них? В первую очередь интересует простота установки nodejs, rabbitmq и т.д; обновление php до актуального состояния.

Comment: Могу сказать, только относительно Ubuntu: много разной документации, статей, есть большое количество форумов с отзывчевой аудиторией (по аналогии с stackoverflow или хэшкод). 

По своему опыту скажу, что когда настраивал сервер под Ubuntu под свои нужды, особых проблем небыло, информацию находил быстро. 

Относительно пакетов: NodeJs в Ubuntu ставиться не просто, а очень просто (есть даже в репах стабильная версия), аналогично и с php, и с rabbitmq тоже быстро и просто настраивается, обновляется. 

Надеюсь, относительно CentOS кто-нибудь расскажет.

Comment: Я поддержу предыдущего комментатора и плюсую за ubuntu. Как мне, то она проще в настройке. Ну и куча мануалов и статей. Большое русскоязычное сообщество.

Comment: @woland, дело привычки (немного разное администрирование). Если изучаете с нуля, то без разницы.

Answer (score 5):

Правильный ответ такой. Если Вы не знаете, какую из двух осей выбрать (а их принципиальное различие в данном случае это то, что одна deb-based, другая rpm-bases), то выбирайте ту, которую лучше знает Ваш любимый/ближайший админ. Многие линуксоиды очень критично относятся, если их спрашивать вопросы не по той оси, которую они любят. А если спрашивать по той, которую любят - то могут очень хорошо помогать.

Так как мы не знаем Вашего админа-соседа, то и не можем рекомендовать.

По своему опыту. На продакшн системы ставят обычно debian, а не ubuntu. Но там более старый (зато проверенный) софт.

Если Ваша домашняя ось убунта, а сервер продакшн - ставьте дебиан. Если сервер тестовый, для экспериментов, ставьте убунту.

Если домашняя ось - другой дистрибутив линукса, то ставьте его или близжайший эквивалент. К примеру, у меня домашняя/рабочая ось это Fedora и Gentoo. А на серверах стоит redhat/CentOS. А вот на свой домашний сервачек поставил недавно убунту, исключительно, чтобы попробовать, как оно. До этого был CentOS и Debian.

Если домашняя ось Windows, тогда смените ее на линукс, и вопрос с этой осью исчерпан.

В случае мака можно, конечно, и макось поставить на сервер ([да, такое есть](https://www.apple.com/osx/server/)). Но можно и FreeBSD.

В целом, если Вы не работали совсем, ставьте убунту, с ним будет проще.

Answer (score -2):

Ubuntu создавалась в первую очередь как десктопная ОС, дружественная пользователю. То, что существуют серверные версии Ubuntu - примерно такое же недоразумение, как и существование серверных версий Windows. Надежда на то, что новоиспеченный "тыжадмин" поставит на сервер что-то знакомое, а не что-то подходящее, во многих случаях оправдываются, к сожалению. Сейчас Вам могут казаться важными такие параметры, как легкость, простота и даже красивость. Это все пройдет с опытом. Если не пройдет, то это уже профнепригодность, извините... Так вот, это пройдет, а ОС останется. Сервер - это не десктоп, там не то что переустановка, там и перезагрузка зачастую рассматривается как аварийная ситуация. Хотя смотря какой сервер, конечно. Я знаю одну организацию, в которой сервер перезагружается раз в несколько дней, когда накапливаются утечки памяти в их софте и винда начинает дико свопить. А клиенты потерпят, должны понимать особенности наши национальные. Вспоминается диалог Кальтенбруннера с офицером, пришедшим просить подмоги для гибнущих ополченцев. «Не пытайтесь пробудить во мне жалость, — отрезает Кальтенбруннер, — это их судьба и выбор. Они же выбрали нас!»

Цитаты из Википедии: "Версии LTS, выпускаемые раз в 2 года, поддерживаются в течение 5 лет — как серверные, так и десктопные варианты. (До версии 12.04 LTS срок поддержки для десктопных LTS-версий составлял 3 года.) На другие дистрибутивы LTS семейства ubuntu действует полная поддержка в 3 года, а для основы системы (ядро, Xorg и прочие компоненты) — 5 лет."

"Срок поддержки каждой версии CentOS составляет 10 лет. Каждая версия обновляется каждые 6 месяцев для поддержки новых аппаратных средств."

Интересная статья в тему - http://petrimazepa.com/ru/giperboleya.html

Comment: что я только что прочитал

Comment: встал человек с утра, видит - не отвеченный вопрос. Дай отвечу. Но сам ещё не проснулся, а спать лег в 7 утра. Но ответить нужно ведь!

Comment: Да, немного сбивчиво получилось... Диалог с Кальтенбруннером - это из фильма "Бункер", если кто не понял. Ссылка - о том, что нужно уметь просчитывать действия на годы вперед, чего большинство россиян не умеет. А просчитывать - надо. Сервер - это не штаны, чтобы каждый год новые примерять, потому что старые порвались или из моды вышли. Так что три-пять лет и десять лет поддержки - это гигантская разница. Это не в два, это в двадцать раз лучше. Зависимость тут нелинейная...

Comment: @VadimTukaev

> Сервер - это не штаны, чтобы каждый год новые примерять

Вообще сейчас сервер как раз-таки разменная монета, причем всякие менеджеры типа chef убивают разницу между ОС просто на раз. Почитайте про immutable infrastructure, например: при каждом обновлении старый сервер убивается и поднимается новый с нуля. Я уж молчу про то, что с приходом докера это все вообще отменилось, переподнимай контейнеры, сколько хочешь, на ОС наплевать, главное чтобы lxc поддерживала.

Comment: @VadimTukaev, а в чем (кроме предустановленных пакетов) вообще, по Вашему мнению, разница между десктопной и серверной убунтой?  
(IMHO ее просто нет ([аналогичные мнения в сети](http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=210591.0))

--

А также, поподробней (если сможете), что же реально отличает сервер от десктопа?

Comment: сервер и декстоп отличаются базовым набором софта и некоторыми оптимизациями. И все.

По софту понятно, Иксы на сервере почти никогда не нужны, а на декстопе без иксов как то скучно.

С настройками другая вещь. К примеру, декстопу нужна "отзывчивость", а вот серверу - что бы побольше переварил запросов. Или к примеру, декстопу нужно иметь возможность иметь побольше исходящих подключений, а входящие вообще можно закрыть фаерволом. С сервером наоборот.

Comment: Разница между десктопной и серверной убунтой небольшая. Это и настораживает. А вот разница между десктопной и серверной CentOS максимально возможная: одна из них существует, а другая - нет. Аналогия: есть приора-седан, есть приора-универсал. В одной помещается два мешка картошки, в другой - три. А есть БелАЗ, у которого легковой модификации нет вообще. Интересно, почему? Казалось бы, ну соптимизируйте там чего-нибудь... Ан нет. Почему же породу из кимберлитовых трубок возят на БелАЗах? Глупые люди! Он стоит как пять-шесть Феррари, а приор вам ваще насыпят в кулечек "с походом"...

Comment: Для центоси есть декстопная версия. Вы можете спокойно ее установить, просто выбрав "установить Иксы". И все работает. Лично проверял.

Но нужно знать историю CentOS. Изначально был RedHat, который предназначен для серверных решений и за деньги. На базе него сделали Fedora Core бесплатная и для декстопов. Потом, энтузиасты посмотрели на это дело и решили, что им нравится RedHat, но денег не хотят платить и сделали на базе доступных rpm пакетов максимально близкое к оригинальному RedHat (и оно сильно близкое).

Выводы делайте сами.

Comment: @VadimTukaev, [в подтверждение комменария](https://www.google.ru/search?hl=ru&as_q=&as_epq=%22argvopt+h%22&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=#newwindow=1&hl=ru&as_qdr=all&q=centos+desktop) от @KoVadim.